# Exception when using Join in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

In trying to get to the bottom of an exception being raised by Rx, I came up with the following repro:

```
[Fact]
public void REPRO()
{
    // when true, window is open to accept requests
    var isWindowOpen = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(true);

    // when this ticks and the window is open, we want to execute the logic
    var request = new Subject<Unit>();

    // determines when the execution window opens
    var openWindow = isWindowOpen
        .Where(ce => ce);

    // determines when the execution window closes
    var closeWindow = isWindowOpen
        .Where(ce => !ce);

    var executionCount = 0;

    var result = Observable
        .Join(
            openWindow,
            request,
            _ => closeWindow,
            _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
            (l, r) => Unit.Default)
        .Do(_ => ++executionCount)
        // changing isWindowOpen from false to true here is causing Rx to throw an exception
        .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(false)).Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(true)))
        .Subscribe();

    // this line causes Rx to throw an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    request.OnNext(Unit.Default);

    Assert.Equal(1, executionCount);
}
```

On the indicated line, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Join`5._.RightObserver.OnNext(TRight value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at RxJoinTest.Class1.InvokeCommandInvokesTheCommand() in c:\users\kent\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RxJoinTest\RxJoinTest\Class1.cs:line 57
```

Notice the commented line that explains the exception occurs only if I modify the `isWindowOpen` observable during the pipeline for a joined item.

Can anyone explain this (seemingly buggy) behavior? Alternatively, can anyone offer another means of achieving my goals whilst circumventing this problem?

My actual scenario is this: the window opening/closing is a command becoming available and unavailable for execution, respectively. The request represents a desire to execute the command, and the logic that executes (inside the `SelectMany`) is the command logic itself. As part of its internal logic, the command disables and then re-enables itself, which is how `isWindowOpen` ends up being modified during the execution.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectMany` in your `Join` code can be reduced to this, which is a bit simpler:

```
var result = Observable.Join(
        openWindow,
        request,
        _ => closeWindow,
        _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
        (l, r) => Unit.Default
    )
    .Do(_ => ++executionCount)
    // The two lines from the SelectMany. You don't even need both; either one of these lines triggers the error
    .Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(false))
    .Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(true))
    .Subscribe();
```

The short answer is that a right window opening can't trigger a change in the left windows, and a left window opening can't trigger a change in the right windows.

Internally, whenever a left window opens, Rx iterates over all the open right windows and executes the Join selector. Since your `.Do`'s are executed immediately and synchronously after the Join selector, they happen while the RightWindowIterator is still open, triggering a modification to the collection RightWindowIterator is iterating over, hence your error. You can peek in the [source code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Join.cs) to confirm this.

This restriction makes sense. If you changed your RightWindowClose function from `Observable.Empty<Unit>()` to `Observable.Never<Unit>()`, and Rx didn't have this restriction, you would have an infinite loop.

As far as helping you achieve your goals, you haven't really described them. Adding a delay before the `.Do`'s will cause them to run asynchronously, so the iterator isn't held open, which would make the code run:

```
var result = openWindow.Join(
        request,
        _ => closeWindow,
        _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
        (l, r) => Unit.Default
    )
    .Do(_ => ++executionCount)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
    .Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(false))
    .Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(true))
    .Subscribe();
```

...however, that is far from reliable robust code. I would suggest eliminating the Subjects as much as possible, and especially the circular logic around them in the Join.

---

**EDIT:**

You can probably achieve the desired effect with the following:

```
var result = request
    .WithLatestFrom(isWindowOpen, (_, windowOpen) => windowOpen)
    .Where(windowOpen => windowOpen)
    .Do(_ => ++executionCount)
    // changing isWindowOpen from false to true here is causing Rx to throw an exception
    .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(false)).Do(__ => isWindowOpen.OnNext(true)))
    .Subscribe();
```

Comment: I've updated my question to give more information on my actual scenario. I think I just need to find a way to avoid the changes being made by the command's internal logic from surfacing in the observables being monitored by `Join`. Will get back to looking at this tonight.

Comment: what is `WithLatestFrom`? Or did you mean `CombineLatest`?

Comment: http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom CombineLatest fires when either parent observable fires. WithLatestFrom fires only when the 'A' parent fires, taking the latest value emitted from the 'B' parent.